# Getting no output on console for big iteration without any error message

Tags: c++, loops, math, sum, iteration

```
int main() {
    int naturalNumber = 2;
    int divider = 0;
    int rest = 1;
    long long int sumOfPrimes = 0;
    while (naturalNumber <= 2000000) {
        divider = naturalNumber;
        while (rest != 0) {
            divider--;
            rest = naturalNumber % divider;
        }
        rest = 1;
        if (divider == 1) {
            sumOfPrimes = sumOfPrimes + naturalNumber;
        }
        naturalNumber++;
    }
    std::cout << sumOfPrimes;
}
```

Howcome does the sum output not appear on the Console after I set the loop condition to go through 2million iterations. And I don't get any error message. It works when it's set to less than ~100'000 iterations. Is this a memory issue or something else?

I was trying to calculate a sum of all primenumbers below 2 million through iteration.

Comment: Weird. I DO get an error message that recommends including iostream.

Comment: Looking over the code I'm thinking that the program just takes an extremely long time to finish. Add `std::cout << naturalNumber << std::endl;` to see how far it's getting before you give up. Note that the `std::endl` will slow the program down even more, but flushing the output's the only easy way to get an accurate representation of when you gave up.

Comment: Recommendation: Find a better way to compute the primes. A [simple sieve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes)  will allow you compute all primes fairly quickly in one pass, and then it's another O(n) loop to sum up the primes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very inefficient way to calculate a series of prime numbers, so the most likely answer is that it's just taking a very very long time.

If you know you need all of the primes up to 2,000,000, the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) is your friend.

Something like:

```
int n = 2000000;
std::vector<bool> is_prime(n+1, true);
is_prime[0] = is_prime[1] = false;
for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
    if (is_prime[i] && (long long)i * i <= n) {
        for (int j = i * i; j <= n; j += i)
            is_prime[j] = false;
    }
}

long long int sum_primes = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (is_prime[i]) sum_primes += i;
}
```

This runs in O(n) complexity, vs. O(n^2).

Comment: Side note: `std::vector<bool>` is typically implemented as a very space-efficient packed bit array. Every boolean value takes up 1 bit. The packing and unpacking of the bits is a wee bit slow, but you're not getting any smaller without significant compression costs. If you are willing to trade a huge increase in storage for speed, you can speed this up noticeably by eliminating the need for packing and unpacking. Also worth noting that in order to hide the packing and unpacking `vector<bool>` doesn't follow all of the normal `vector` rules.

Comment: [See the documentation for details](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool). Yes, its different enough to get it's own doc page.

Comment: Could you cut the time in half by only iterating through the odd numbers? Also, should the inner `for` loop start from `2 * i` (not form `i * i`)?